# Should I include Calendar functionality into my android App? (Is calendar pre-installed on most phones?)

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, linkify

I was thinking of including functionality to allow users to click on dates in the "important dates" section of my app, but was wondering if it is safe to assume that most phones have Google calendar pre-installed.

I was planning on writing a custom filter to Linkify the dates and pass them to the calendar app as an event.

This project is planned for 1.6, but 2.1 is also a possibility. (Trying to reach the largest possible audience)

Comment: The Calendar application from the Android open source project has no documented and supported API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calendar installed on most Android devices except some, that not "licensed" Android platform (e.g. devices from Chinese vendors).

And as far as I know if device have Market app, then it have Calendar also. So if you don't planning use alternative markets you may assume that Calendar is pre-installed.